# Check if a parameter $1 is a three-character all-caps string

Tags: bash

How can I check if the parameter inserted $1 is a string of 3 chars in uppercase? For example ABG. another example: GTD

Thanks

Comment: `$1` is **always** a string. If it exists at all, it can never be anything except a string.

Comment: Even if it's a string that represents a number, or an empty string, it's still a string.

Comment: To explain why, check `man execve` -- the syscall that UNIX programs use to start other programs. The argument vector, from which `$0`/`$1`/etc. are populated, is of type `char *const argv[]`. Nothing but a string can be passed that way. The shell follows that same convention for functions or other internal calls.

Comment: Anyhow -- what's the actual _practical problem_ you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, I want to check if the argument $1 is a string of three chars, for example ABC or HGF  (also the chars must be in uppercase)

Comment: Would have been helpful if the question had been asked that way in the first place. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using bash-only regular expression syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $1 =~ ^[[:upper:]]{3}$ ]]; then
  echo "The first argument is three upper-case characters"
else
  echo "The first argument is _not_ three upper-case characters
fi
```

...or, for compatibility with all POSIX shells, one can use a `case` statement:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  [[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]])
    echo "The first argument is three upper-case characters";;
  *)
    echo "The first argument is _not_ three upper-case characters";;
esac
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much! What about if I want to let the user to introduce many arguments but the condition is the same that it has to be three chars in uppercase? for example script.sh ASH HSG , another example script.sh HDG GSH HSG JGE NDJ SGY HSG

Comment: Then instead of using `$1`, do something like `for arg in "$@"; do ...; done`, and use `"$arg"` inside that loop.

Comment: And the code to ckeck if the argument is a string of three uppercase chars must be inside the loop , right?

Comment: Right; you put the check inside the loop, and change `case $1` to `case $arg` (or `[[ $1 =~ ...` to `[[ $arg =~ ...`).

Comment: I have a small problem, that loop is for all the arguments, but my first argument is a file, so i would like the loop to check the arguments from argument 2 onwards.               This is a real example: script.ch file.txt ABF JGJ KJD KHE

Comment: You can `shift` off your first argument. `file=$1; shift; for arg in "$@"; do ...` will only loop over `$2` and on.

Comment: perfect! thanks :)

Comment: When a question is solved to your satisfaction, you can mark it that way by clicking the checkbox next to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
LC_ALL=C

[[ "$1" == [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] ]] || exit 1
```

Or

```
LC_ALL=C

if [[ "$1" != [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] ]]; then
    echo "$1: invalid input" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

As per Charles' comment, `A-Z` is a character range, which is not equivalent to "all upper case latin letters" in all locales, so we can set the locale with `LC_ALL=C`.

You can use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` if you don't want to set `LC_ALL=C`.

Alternatively, there's `shopt -s globasciiranges`, but it only works in bash version 4.3 or later (and is set by default in version 5.0 and later).

Note also, that using glob patterns in a string comparison is bash specific, and won't work in `sh`.

Comment: `[A-Z]` isn't correct on all locales. Some alphabets are ordered like `AaBbCc...Zz`, making `A-Z` include lower-case letters; others have letters before `A` or after `Z`, making it not fully inclusive. This code will be fine where `LC_ALL=C`, but that's not true everywhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes good point, I did forget that. However, this is actually fine in bash >= v5.0, because the shell option `globasciiranges` is set by default. The option itself was added in v4.3. You would generally want more portability than that though. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Nice -- I didn't know about that feature! It doesn't work so well if the op _wants_ `À` or `Ä` to be considered an upper-case letter (and their locale reflects that preference), but certainly will be helpful to predictability once bash 5.x or later is ubiquitous.